# Access an Image from Image Collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have created code which accesses  Sentinel 2 images, clip them according to a shapefile I have and calculate NDVI for the whole image collection.
Now, I want to visualize the images I have created, to see them as a layer and maybe after even export them.
 I tried to change the ImageCollection into a list and then use "get" in order to create variable out of the images, but it didn't work and I get this error message anytime I try to visualize the images:

```
 Cannot add an object of type <ComputedObject> to the map.
```

I tried it also on the image collection before all the calculations, when it was a bunch of Sentinel images, but I got the same error.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
}

// Map the function over one year of data 
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2015-06-23', '2019-07-02')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
var clippedCol=dataset.map(function(im){ 
   return im.clip(geometry);
});

print(clippedCol);


//function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
  .rename('NDVI')
  .copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
  return image.addBands(ndvi);

};

//NDVI to the clipped image collection
var withNDVI = clippedCol.map(addNDVI).select('NDVI');

var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};

var listOfImages = withNDVI.toList(withNDVI.size());
print('List:',listOfImages);
var img1 = listOfImages.get(0);

Map.addLayer(img1,colorizedVis,'img1');
```

The end goal is to be able to visualize any image I want from the ImageCollection and to be able to export it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Earth Engine the elements inside an `ImageCollection` are `Image` but inside a `List` are just `Element`, so the system doesn't know it is an `Image` what you are getting from it. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#client-side-errors).

To solve this you just have to "cast" it:

```js
var img1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
```